# Writing values from one table to another in MySQL using Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
File path = new File("/Users/Zack/Desktop/JavaDB/BALANCESHEETS");
    for(File file: path.listFiles()) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            String fileName = file.getName();
            String ticker = fileName.split("\\_")[0];
            String writeCompanyValues = "INSERT INTO BALANCESHEET (companies_id, Companies, ticker) "
                                        + "SELECT companies_id, Companies, ticker FROM companies WHERE ticker = " + ticker;
            statement.executeUpdate(writeCompanyValues);

        }
    }
```

I have company tickers (such as AAPL) stored in the ticker String, and have a column named ticker in my companies table. I want to find a row with that ticker and copy over that rows data into the balance sheet table.

I'm getting the error Exception in thread "main"

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'AAPL' in 'where clause'
```

Any ideas on how to copy data this way?

Comment: Check in your database table if the AAPL column exists?

Comment: can you please share whether you are using statement or prepared statement?

Comment: I have read the question @Scary Wombat, look at the exception posted by the user?

Comment: @ManishSakpal *I have company tickers (such as AAPL) stored in the ticker String*

Comment: OK @Scary Wombat i wasn't aware of what are company tickers as i don't work in company, hence I misunderstood it. Sorry my apologies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead of string concatenation to avoid this sort of problem. And to safeguard against SQL injection (which as suggested as an addition by Scary Wombat). The error here is due to a missing quote

```
"SELECT companies_id, Companies, ticker FROM companies WHERE ticker = '" + ticker +"'";
```

Alternatively

```
String writeCompanyValues = "INSERT INTO BALANCESHEET (companies_id, Companies, ticker) "
                                        + "SELECT companies_id, Companies, ticker FROM companies WHERE ticker = ?";

stmt = con.prepareStatement(writeCompanyValues);
stmt.setString(1, ticker);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: *You should use prepared statements* also safe-guards against SQL Injection

Comment: Thanks, this did work, I did forget the two quotes " ' ' ". I'll take note on the prepared statements, and I also never created the columns to begin with on the BalanceSheet table.